# How to access a C flag in Android NDK?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have this in my `jni/Android.mk` file:

```
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -LANG=en
```

But LANG does not exist when I run the program!  Any ideas?

Comment: I am not aware of any cflag LANG, do you probably mean `LOCAL_CFLAGS := -DLANG=en` (in order to have a define)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use -D option instead:

LOCAL_CFLAGS := -D LANG=en

It's equivalent to the C #define. You then use LANG as a constant with value `en`. Note that it's not a string "en", it's an unquoted identifier. So the following usage is fine:

```
int en = 1, de = 2, es = 3;

int CurrentLang = LANG; //Translates to CurrentLang = en;
```

Or like this:

```
#if LANG==en
//English localization stuff...
#endif
```

While the following is not:

```
char * CurrentLang = LANG; //Error: en is an unknown identifier. It's not a string.
```

Comment: Thanks, the -D was what I was missing.  Also, I'm using a 'stringify' macro that extracts the string value.  `#define STRINGIFY(arg) #arg` followed by `#define STR_VALUE(arg) STRINGIFY(arg)`.  And finally `#define K_LANG STR_VALUE(LANG)`, which gives me K_LANG with a value of "en".

Comment: Is a space tolerated between `-D` and `LANG`? I am used to see `-DLANG=en`.